# Distinguishing Between Overloaded Generic and Non-Generic Methods

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

This must be covered somewhere but I'm having difficulty expressing my search criteria, so...

Below are three instance methods declared by the same type.

```
void Invoke(int timeout);
void Invoke<T>(T data);
T Invoke<T>(int timeout);
```

I want to invoke the second method, passing an Int32 argument and without using reflection.  Options include:

```
Invoke(1);
Invoke<int>(1);
Invoke((int)1);
Invoke<int>((int)1);
```

However, none of these calls the desired method.  Can I achieve what I want or should I resort to method-renaming?

Note that if the third method did not exist, I could simply do this:

```
Invoke(1); // Invokes the first method
Invoke<int>(1); // Invokes the second method
```

Comment: Isn't a solution of your issue naming arguments when you pass it? Invoke(timeout: 1);

Comment: Good grief, so it is.  I've been doing this for years and had no idea that was possible.

Comment: Hope it helped ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: Yeah, optional arguments I know.  Not sure how I missed the named-argument stuff though.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using named arguments:

```
Invoke(data: 1);
```